# What PHP function(s) should I use to cut off the end of a string?

Tags: php, string

I have a filename stored with the directory as a value.

Ex. /var/www/remove_this.php

In my PHP script I want to remove everthing after the last '/', so I can use mkdir on this path without creating a directory from the filename also.

There are so many string editing functions, I don't know a good approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[dirname()](http://php.net/dirname) will return you the directory part of the path

Answer (score 2):

Use [`pathinfo()`](http://php.net/pathinfo) to get info about the file itself.

```
$file = '/var/www/remove_this.php';
$pathinfo = pathinfo($file);
$dir = $pathinfo['dirname']; // '/var/www/'
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use string functions, but for this case PHP has some smarter directory functions:

```
$dir = dirname('/var/www/remove_this.php'); // /var/www
```

[pathinfo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) is an excellent one as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$file="/var/www/remove_this.php";
$folder=dirname($var);
if (!file_exsts($folder))
{
  if (mkdir($folder,777,true))
  {
    echo "Folder created\n";
  } else
  {
    echo "Folder creation failed\n";
  }
} else
{
  echo "Folder exists already\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: the mode should be 0777 - it's octal number. with 777 the folder is with dr----x--t permission

Comment: Would is_dir() be the same as file_exists() in this case? Since I am testing for a dir I think it would be more appropriate. Thanks for this great response though!

Comment: @KRB dir is kind of file. You can check with is_dir(), however if there is a file with the same name, is_dir() will return false, but mkdir may fail.